# I want to delete any locally installed package from my Linux machine and use directly only packages from environment

Tags: linux, pip, anaconda, pymongo, dnspython

I am in Linux system and i have 3 different anaconda environments. My issue is that probably i installed some packages locally and i cannot find them. Into the environments the rest users cannot see **dnspython, certifi and pymongo packages**. I am the only user that can see those packages. I want to find and delete any local package so i can use the environments with no extra packages. For example i just create a new env with name **xx** and when i run `pip freeze` i have already 3 pckgs.
[image: pip freeze]

The rest users when they get into this **xx** env cannot see any installed package with `pip freeze` so that's why i think that i've made something locally. Also with `conda list` i cannot see dnspython and pymongo packages.

[image: conda list]

I had install them through pip but with `conda list` probably you must also see pip packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find what's was going wrong. I had installed locally packages.

- With `pip list --user` you can see all your locally pip packages.
- With `python -m site --user-site` you can see the location of those
  locally installed packages.
- With `rm -rf *` you can delete all packages inside the site-packages dir.

It was into : **/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages**